# $.ajax & passing data to .asmx webservice

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, jquery

I'm quite confused as to why this is happening.

I can't seem to pass data successfully via `$.ajax`, the URL gets all mangled up instead of the data being passed in a query string.

***I've cleaned up the code for brevity, see below.***

**Webservice (using GET)**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string TestMethod(string country, string city)
{
    return country + city;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Test.asmx/TestMethod",
    type: "GET",
    data: '{"country":"' + country + '","city":"' + city + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

**Resulting URL and Error (in Firebug)**

```
http://example.com/Test.asmx/TestMethod?{%22country%22:%22NZ%22,%22city%22:%22AK%22}
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: country.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change

`data: '{"country":"' + country + '","city":"' + city + '"}'`

To

`data: "country="+country+"&city="+city`

Comment: Or you could change the `contentType` to `application/json`. (http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: @xdazz so the 'data' portion just gets appended to the URL huh? Well that's good to know haha, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marko if it's a string yes. If it's an object no. If you remove the plings before { and after } you'd see a different behavior than the one you describe

Comment: @Marko make that if you removed the plings and and double plings ie { country:country, ...}

Answer (score 1):

Adding a **"contentType"** property to the options list would be the easiest change in my mind.

I also use `JSON.stringify()` to reduce the introduction of quotation errors.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Test.asmx/TestMethod",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ country: country, city: city }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```