# How can I send parameters for ASP.NET webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, post, get, asmx

I have an university project where I should implement a java powered website that uses web services: some that will be created as servlets and others that should be created as .NET "servlets". I created the java servlet that can be called as /loginservice/username="__________"&md5="____________". All good.
Now I must implement another service in .NET. I created a ASP.NET web service application but this type of application uses POST instead of GET. I found out that this could be changed by adding

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
```

but the problem is that I can't pass parameters like I do in Java.
There is no way of using POST anywhere because I don't want to rewrite the code in Java.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace t5_services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
   // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
        public string Package(String packagename, String lastname)
        {
            return "Hello " + packagename + ": " + lastname;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code in C#
If I use the browser and manually insert the values all is ok.[image]

But I can't use the GET convention.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for the info. The big problem is that Microsoft retires technologies too fast. For a newbie like me, it is really hard to find a good tutorial on a new subject. Also, I'm not really interested in Microsoft web technologies, but I have an university assignment, and I must obey the rules.

Comment: WCF is not a new technology. It's been here since 2006. Your university is far behind the times.

Comment: Maybe you deal everyday with WCF subjects. But for me, and perhaps my university this topic is still hot :)). The university curricula drives us from the beginning of the universe, if I could say so. :D.

Comment: Not to slight Señor Saunders, but Nucandrei is correct. WCF is hard to configure without very much in terms of performance gain, if you ask me. Though sometimes 10% is critical, most of the time, ASMX is much more forgiving to configure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally solve the problem by removing

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
```

and adding

```
<webServices>
     <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
     </protocols>
</webServices>
```

to Web.config

Now I can call the service using

```
http://localhost:2586/Service1.asm/HelloWorld?parameter1=abc&parameter2=cde
```

Comment: Well done for finding a solution and thank you for posting it up here for future visitors.

Comment: For future visitors, Put `webServices` part inside `<configuration>
  <system.web>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how I do it in WCF.  I'm sure it will be very similar for your Asp.net service.  If nothing else, it should point you in the right direction.

This is your function declaration in your interface file.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "DoWork?message={message}&message2={message2}")]
string DoWork(string message, string message2);
```

This goes into a class that implements that interface.

```
    public string DoWork(string message, string message2)
    {
        return "foobar";
    }
```

Your GET request would then look something like http://yoursite.com/DoWork?message=param1&message2=param2

Comment: I created a WCF and write the code that you provided. When I enter localhost:1290/Service1.svc/DoWork?message1=acg&message2=msga a blank page appears.

Comment: Do you have httpGetEnabled=true in your web.config?

Comment: I found the solution. See below answer. One of the problems was that GET was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Sorry for the short reply, just packing up to go home.

[$.ajax & passing data to .asmx webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577840/ajax-passing-data-to-asmx-webservice)

Comment: I needed a browser url to enter so I could check that service is working. The service will be used in JSF (JavaServerFaces) and has nothing to do with jQuery.